# Arguments giving more then 1 word

Tags: discord.js

I made a mute command and I try use ms to mute for the time specified and when I log what the time says it gives back 1m (reason) instead of just 1m

```
'mute': async (msg) => {
    if(!msg.guild.member(msg.author).hasPermission('MUTE_MEMBERS')) { return msg.channel.send("Hmmm... I don't think you're allowed to use that. Missing permission: Mute Members.") }
    if(!msg.guild.member(bot.user).hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) { return msg.channel.send("Uh oh, you have permission to use the command but it seems I do not. Missing permission: Manage channels.")}
    let embedError = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("RED")
    .setTitle("Error")
    .setDescription("Correct format:\nAlexa mute [user eg: @YxriDev#0001] [time eg: 1h] [reason eg: Spamming.]")
    let args = msg.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')
    let time = msg.content.split(' ').slice(3).join(' ')
    let reason = msg.content.split(' ').slice(4).join(' ')

    let muting = msg.mentions.users.first()
    if(!muting) { return msg.channel.send(embedError) }
    if(!time)  { return msg.channel.send(embedError) }
    if(!reason) { return msg.channel.send(embedError) }

      msg.guild.channels.forEach(x => {
        x.overwritePermissions(muting, {
          SEND_MESSAGES: false,
          VIEW_CHANNEL: null,
        })
      })
      msg.channel.send("Muted")
      console.log(time)

      setTimeout(function() {
        msg.guild.channels.forEach(x => {
          x.overwritePermissions(muting, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: null,
          })
        })
        msg.channel.send("unmuted")
    }, ms(time))

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your slicing is incorrect. And you are unnecessarily creating a new array for each argument.

Try this one:
It only uses one `.split()`, which returns an array containing all space-separated words. Then you can use Array-destructing to get the words into variables (`let [a] = [42];` will store `42` in `a`) and group the remaining words (the reason) back into an array which can be easily joined back into a string using `.join()`.

```js
const msg = {
  content: 'Alexa mute @user 1h You spammed!'
};

let [, , , time, ...reason] = msg.content.split(' ');
reason = reason.join(' ');

console.log(time);
console.log(reason);
```

Comment: @YxriDev if this answer has fixed your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark below the vote counter. This way people will now the question is solved and can find the working solution much easier